# Chef: attributes get overriden based on 'depends' order

Tags: chef-infra

I've got next deployment scheme:

- two servers that should be deployed together on the same machine
- their common attributes - hostname, port, default username and password
- specific attributes - e.g. context path

So, I created base cookbook and specified there all the common options. After that I create two dependent cookbooks with particular recipes to run both servers and set specific attributes values. And this thing had worked until I decided to have another wrapper cookbook
which purpose is to start both servers and do some extra stuff.

I configured the topmost cookbook in the next way:

```
metadata.rb:
    depends "app1"
    depends "app2"

recipe.rb:
    include_recipe "app1::start"
    include_recipe "app2::start"
```

The thing is that 'include_recipe "app1::start"' sees attributes overriden by 'app2' cookbook.
So if I change order in metadata.rb to:
depends "app2"
depends "app1"

Then 'include_recipe "app2::start"' sees attributes overriden by 'app1' cookbook.

What should I do to limit a scope of attributes for the included resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should scope the attributes in the node object

```
node['app1']['attribute1']
node['app2']['attribute2']
```

And in each recipe use the correct scope for `app1` or `app2`

Chef load all attributes files to build the node object prior to creating the resource collection in copile phase, so there's no way to avoid this on the same node.

I don't see how you did make that work with separate cookbooks, unless different runs with different runlist (which would change the node object for each run.

See [this doc on chef-run](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html) for detail on the steps.

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do if common attributes exist for both objects? Just do something like `node['app1']['common1'] = node.default['common1']`?

Comment: Commons attributes may stay in place and be used as-is in each app recipe (as long as they have the same value for all the apps of course)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should scope your attributes, like Tensaibai said.  For the most part, common attributes should only exist if they are indeed common, in which case, you'd want BOTH cookbooks to see the same value.

Secondly, you can control the order in which attributes are loaded by using the `include_attribute` directive in your attribute files.  So your wrapper cookbook could contain these lines in `wrapper-cookbook/attributes/default.rb`

```
include_attribute 'app1::default'
include_attribute 'app2::default'
```

That will ensure that app1's attributes load first.  Either way, all attribute files will be loaded prior to ANY recipes being run.